# getUrl dropping _format when set to json

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to generate a url and set the _format variable to json.  the .json part is never added to the route.  setting to html or xml appends the format correctly.

The route from `app/console router:debug`,

```
api_1_get_page  GET      ANY    ANY  /api/page/{id}.{_format}
```

And my functional test code,

```
$this->getUrl('api_1_get_page', array('id' => $page->getId(), '_format' => 'json'));
```

when I dump this I get,

```
string(18) "/api/pages/1"
```

Whereas,

```
$this->getUrl('api_1_get_page', array('id' => $page->getId(), '_format' => 'html'));
```

returns `string(18) "/api/pages/1.html"`

I'm guessing there is a setting controlling this, I've tried setting every fos_rest config setting on and off and nothing is making a difference.  This is also causing me issues when tests are checking the Location: header expecting .json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set .json as the default format in your route?

If you're using FOSRestBundle look at `routing_loader` [in the FOSRestBundle config](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration-reference.md)

See: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#routing

Comment: I have,  routing_loader: default_format: json & include_format: true.  Removing the default doesn't change the output of getUrl though.

Comment: What does your `getUrl` function look like?

Comment: so turns out there is a test cache.  I've been clearing dev and prod cache for the last couple of days.  Thanks for the help mate, what you've posted is correct.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you got it sorted. I would have thought the dev cache would clear itself just like dev. Good to know.